# Quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ by $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'd like help for the problem:

Let the additive group $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ act on $\mathbb{R}$ on the right by $x · 2\pi n = x+2\pi n$, where $n$ is an integer. Show that the orbit space $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{2\pi n\mathbb{Z}} $  is a smooth manifold.

I proved that $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{2\pi n\mathbb{Z}} $ is hausdorff and second countable, but I don't know how to find an atlas, I was thinking about $ \psi([x])=e^{ix}$ but I don't know how to show that this is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Keep in mind the geometric interpretation that $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ is a circle.

Comment: A continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces is an homeo.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I'm under the impression that that's a rather hefty theorem though.

Comment: @AlexBecker the idea is to conclude that,so suppose I don't know this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez How does one know that $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{2\pi \mathbb{Z}} is compact?

Comment: It is the image of $[0,2\pi]$ under the projection map.

Comment: Alex: not really. Since the function $f$ we start with is bijective, it has an inverse, so we want to show it is continuous: it is more or less obvious that it is enough to show that the image under $f$ of a closed set is closed. Closed sets in the domain are compact, the continuous image of a compact set is compact, and in the codomain compacts are closed. In any case, I'd expect this little piece of general topology to be known by anyone who knows the definition of a smooth manifold... His life *will* be hard if not!

Comment: @AlexBecker I think the that the "theorem" is a consequence of the definition of homeomorphism

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sure! Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4):

This is easier to do in general than in the special case, so I'll just generalize.
Most of the claims below *require* proof, by the way!

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and that $G$ is a group which acts on $M$ smoothly and properly discontinuously. Let $N=M/G$ be the quotient topological space and $\pi:M\to N$ the quotient map. Since the action is properly discontinuous, $N$ is Hausdorff and the map $\pi$ is open —in particular, the second-countability of $M$ implies that of $N$.

Let us now construct an atlas.

Let $p\in M$. Proper-discontinuity implies there is an open neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$ such that $U\cap gU=\emptyset$ for all $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$. The restriction $\pi|_U:U\to N$ is an homeomorphism onto its image, which is open in $N$. By replacing $U$ by a smaller open neighborhood of $p$, we can suppose that there is a chart $\phi:V\to\mathbb R^n$ in the (maximal) atlas of $M$ with $U\subseteq V$. We define $\psi_p=\phi\circ(\pi|_U)^{-1}:\pi(U)\to\mathbb R^n$.

Now the set $\mathcal A=\{\psi_p:p\in M\}$ is an atlas on $N$.

Comment: Why not take the most natural idea: restrict the quotient map $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow S^1$ to any open Intervall $I$ of length $<1$. It is then clear that $f|_I$ is injective and continous. Now show that it is open and  that the coordinate changes $f_J^{-1} f_I$ are smooth.

Comment: @Blah, Dear Blah, that is *precisely* what I did above, modulo the observation that the standard atlas on $\mathbb R$ contains the identity function $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Mariano, sorry for my duplicate: Of course you are right, I just wanted to give a hint that the atlas can be constructed really elementary.

Comment: sorry but, what is "acts on $M$ smoothly and properly discontinuously",and why this is the case of the action above?

Comment: That the action be smooth meansthat each element acts by a diffeo of $M$. The definition of "properly discontinuously" you will find in Wikipedia.

Comment: How to prove that $\psi$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: You cannot prove that $\psi$ is $C^\infty$: it does not make sense! I am using the maps $\psi$ to construct the atlas... What you probably want is to ask is «how can I prove that the transition functions of the atlas I constructed are smooth?»

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez No,I mean look $\psi$ a function between two spaces.

Comment: I don't understand your clarification :/

Comment: $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{2 \pi \mathbb{Z}}$ is a smooth manifold so is $\mathbb{S}^1$, it does make sense talk about differentiability of a function between manifolds.